# Tex Live installation failure - I get an error at the end of installation

Tags: errors, texlive, installing, windows, texlive-2016

Currently I am writing a scientific book about space.
I had problems installing MikTex so I dicided to install Tex Live.
I removed the miktex files by deleting them.
I disabled my antivirus.
Then i run the installation of Tex Live.
At the end of installation after a couple of hours the attached messsage appeared.
No icon of Tex Live at Start menu or shortcut at desktop.
Windows 7 64-bit

Here is while installing:

[image]

The error:

[image]

Comment: Exactly how are you installing and why is the first image running in a temp area? Are you by any chance using `install-tl.exe`? I'd recommend downloading the zip instead, unzip it (don't run the installer directly from the zip), then from the unzipped folder run `install-tl-advanced.bat ` and just use the default settings.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.